# Zend Framework Form Submit Button Style

Tags: forms, zend-framework, button, zend-form, form-submit

Is it possible to change the form's Submit button from the defaut - like the Gmail button say, which is blue?
Currently I have this in my form:

```
$this->addElement('submit', 'form_element_signup', array('label' => 'Sign up',
                                                                 'tabindex' => 20,
                                                                 'decorators' => array('ViewHelper',
                                                                                        array(array('div' => 'HtmlTag'),
                                                                                               array ('tag' => 'button',
                                                                                                      'class' => 'action blue')))));
```

But this still gives me the default submit button within my div button.

Answer (score 2):

you can add your custom class with your own css property like below

```
$this->addElement(new Zend_Form_Element_Button( 'send',
                   array( 'label' => 'registrieren', 
                          'class' => 'button-red', 
                          'type' => 'submit',
                          'escape' => false,
                          'required' => false,
                           'ignore' => false, ) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes just apply the appropriate CSS to the 'div', 'tag' or 'class' as required.
[22 CSS Button Styling Tutorials and Techniques](http://speckyboy.com/2009/05/27/22-css-button-styling-tutorials-and-techniques/) may help.